# CakePHP 3: Why not to using Session in model

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I think it is necessary to access the session data from every where especially in the model, I don't know what is the conflict with the design or logic of CakePHP.

I wonder if we can use the Session class globally as Text class.

Does the problem just about the design and logic and nothing related to errors can be rises in the future?

Comment: what is an example of why/when you would want to access the session in a model?

Comment: if you like this aswer please mark as right anwer.. :)

Comment: Hi @AD7six, the session is made to store the variables globally, so we will need these variables to store in model or filter by it

Comment: You haven't addresssed my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Framework concept you can read/write/modify session from Controller.But have not read and write access in Model.

In CakePHP v3  you can manage session in model as mentioned below

```
\Cake\Routing\Router::getRequest()->session()->read('key');
\Cake\Routing\Router::getRequest()->session()->write('key', 'value');
```

Comment: With Session helper you can not write/edit/delete session.. but yes you can use \Cake\Routing\Router::getRequest()->session() in view also.

Refer Cake Document for Session Helper http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/session.html

Comment: Ohk... thanks Very much for update me...!!!!!, I have modified my answer